# How do i center my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I have a script here for my navigation bar:

```
<style type="text/css">
 /* Navigation Bar */
 #nav_bar {
     display:inline-block;
     height:50px;
 }
 #nav_bar ul {
     display:inline-block;
     list-style-type: none;
     border: 1px solid red;
     width: 565px;
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
 }
 #nav_bar li {
     display:inline;
     height:100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
 }
 #nav_bar a:hover {
     background-color: #000000;
 }
 #nav_bar a {
     display:inline-block;
     height: 100%;
     color:white;
     text-decoration:none;
     line-height: 50px;
     padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
     background-color: #900000;
 }
</style>
</font>
```

I'm having trouble trying to get it displayed in the centre of the page, how can I do it?
I've looked into "display: inline-block;" and "position: relative" and couldn't find a code that worked
the html part of my nav bar is as follows (in regards to your comments) I hope it helps! :)

```
<div id="nav_bar">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Forums</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Shipping Info</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Contact us</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">About us</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can use `text-align:center` under `#nav_bar`, that could work, but without more code (HTML) it's hard to say.

Comment: You might want to add the HTML containing `#nav_bar` to your post.

Comment: like this you mean?
<div id="nav_bar">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Forums</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Shipping Info</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Contact us</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">About us</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/29FRa/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a width and auto margins and make sure its a block level element.

By default a 'div' is a block level element so you can remove this rule.

You must set a width or the menu with expand to the width of its container.

```
#nav_bar {
     display:block;
     height:50px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 567px; /* or whatever you require */
 }
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/29FRa/

Comment: But remove the display: inline-block;

Comment: this has worked i'll accept it as an answer in 3 minutes... when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

```
 #nav_bar {
   height:50px;
   width:800px;
   margin:0 auto;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="#nav_bar"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parent needs a defined width.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: center;` on your `#nav_bar` and be sure it is a block-level element.

http://jsfiddle.net/TKMeU/

Answer (score 0):

A total of six kinds of methods：
１、Margin and width to achieve horizontal center

```
#nav_bar {
     height:50px;
 }
 #nav_bar ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     border: 1px solid red;
     width: 565px;
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0;
     margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/iezmA).
2、use the inline-block, like this:

```
#nav_bar {
     height:50px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 #nav_bar ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid red;
     width: 565px;
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    word-spacing: -4px;
 }
 #nav_bar li {
    margin: 0 5px;
   display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom:1;
  letter-spacing: normal;  
  word-spacing: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
 }
```

please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/GbfvF).

3、use the float,like this:

```
#nav_bar {
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
 }
 #nav_bar ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     width: 565px;
      height: 50px;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     clear: left;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      left: 50%;/*整个分页向右边移动宽度的50%*/
      text-align: center;
 }
 #nav_bar li {
     margin: 0 5px;
     display: block;
     height: 50px;
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     right: 50%;/*将每个分页项向左边移动宽度的50%*/
 }
 #nav_bar a:hover {
     background-color: #000000;
 }
 #nav_bar a {
     display:block;
     height: 100%;
     color:white;
     text-decoration:none;
     line-height: 50px;
     padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
     background-color: #900000;
 }
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/rLbpD).

Other methods, you can click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/elements-horizontally-center-with-css.html).